# Integral with exponential and polynomial in denominator

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I've been working on
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+4)-x(x+1)e^{x-0.5x^2}} dx.
\end{align}

I struggle to simplify the denominator. Does anyone have a suggestion how I could continue with the integral?

---

I tried something like partial fractions. Let $\mathcal{P}(x)=(x+2)(x+4)$ and $\mathcal{E}(x)=e^{x-0.5x^2}$. Then, $$\frac{1}{x(x+1)(\mathcal{P}(x)-\mathcal{E}(x))}=\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-\frac{\mathcal{P}(x)-\mathcal{E}(x)-1}{x(x+1)(\mathcal{P}(x)-\mathcal{E}(x))}$$ and the first term is easy now but I'm again not sure how to proceed.

---

I'm grateful for @Henry Lee's suggestion to do a substitution which changes the exponential to a single quadratic term, $e^{-0.5x^2}$, similar to how it appears in the Gaussian bell curve. But this didn't help me to greatly simplify further calculations.

Comment: Is there any reason a closed form representation should exist?

Comment: Please provide some more information related to the problem. First of all, which is the source? Partial fraction decomposition does not apply, because there is no rational function to be integrated, no polynomial in $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: @epiliam I'm not 100% sure that a closed form solution exists but I'm hopeful. I don't see a reason why no closed form solution should exist. Perhaps I'm just overseeing something. But I hope someone here could help me with simplifying/decomposing the denominator

Comment: @dan_fulea what extra information would you need? I know that standard partial fractions don’t apply. I mentioned this trivial decomposition (which I called _something like_ a partial fraction decomposition) in my post, $\frac{1}{a(x)(b(x)+c(x))}=\frac{1}{a(x)}+\frac{1-b(x)-c(x)}{a(x)(b(x)+c(x))}$ but it didn’t make anything easier.  So I seek an alternative way how to deal with the sum in the denominator.

Comment: Which is the source of the problem? Using a lot of new letters and the "something like" try to do something is not providing enough context. The question is "Does anyone have a suggestion how I could continue?" The answer is either "No", which should be accepted with many votes, but ok, instead of this plain answer, the suggestion was to provide the **source** of the problem, so that people have an information. Note that not every function can be integrated using "elementary functions".

Comment: @Alex while you "don't see a reason why no closed form solution should exist", I see no reason why a closed form solution would exist. If you just slap together some polynomials and exponentials in an integral it is very unlikely to exist as a finite sum of elementary functions. The only reason a closed form solution would exists is: A. you are very, very lucky, B. there is some inherent symmetry of the problem - for which we would need to see the derivation of the problem to determine.

Comment: @epiliam Good point. Most integrals can’t be computed in closed form. But I don’t approach a problem thinking “nothing will work anyway”. After working on this for some time, I thought I may ask here. Perhaps someone spots a new direction of what could work or what could rewrite the denominator. My _actual_ problem would include a bunch of additional parameters and functions and I won’t write down all these (unrelated) details. It just boils down to an integral like in the question. But given that it arises in an application, I’ve some hope that something useful can be done with the integrand.

Comment: Where has this integral come from? If it isn't just random there may be a better way to arrive at the answer

Answer (score 2):

this is not a full answer but a few suggestions:
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+4)-x(x+1)e^{x-0.5x^2}}=\int\frac{1}{x(x+1)}\frac{dx}{(x+2)(x+4)-e^{x-0.5x^2}}$$
now we can see that:
$$x-\frac{x^2}{2}=-\frac12\left(x^2-2x\right)=-\frac12\left[(x-1)^2-1\right]$$
so potentially with a substitution $u=x-1$ we end up with:
$$I=\int\frac{1}{(u+1)(u+2)}\frac{du}{(u+4)(u+6)-e^{1/2}e^{-u^2/2}}$$